# Trying to add social media icons to the top left of top bar

Tags: html, css, web, navigation, icons

Need help adding social media icons on the left side of the top bar on our website using html. I added this top bar using html so i wouldn't mind adding a new code with the left aligned social media icons, i have the photos so just need the code. Also, trying to add menu separators for each item and i am not sure how to do that either. Website: http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/

```css
     
     #navbar ul { 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 10px; 
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: right; 
     background-color: #000; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li {  
     display: inline; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li a { 
     text-decoration: none; 
     padding: .2em 1em; 
     color: #fff; 
     background-color: #000; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li a:hover { 
     color: #000; 
     background-color: #fff; 
     } 
     
     #navbar{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
        width: 100%;
        }
     nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{
    
       top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
                  the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
                  from the top of the page.*/
    
      }
```

```html
    <div id="navbar"> 
      <ul>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="active" href="about">facebook</a></li>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="active" href="#about">twitter</a></li>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="active" href="#about">linkedin</a></li>
     <li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li> 
     <li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li> 
     <li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li> 
     <li><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML and CSS as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I added a few lines of code at bottom of the css file. In html file i added img tag inside the respective tags. Hope it will help you.

```css
#navbar ul { 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 10px; 
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: right; 
     background-color: #000; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li {  
     display: inline; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li a { 
     text-decoration: none; 
     padding: .2em 1em; 
     color: #fff; 
     background-color: #000; 
     } 
     
    #navbar ul li a:hover { 
     color: #000; 
     background-color: #fff; 
     } 
     
     #navbar{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
        width: 100%;
        }
     nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{
    
       top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
                  the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
                  from the top of the page.*/
    
      }

.social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar"> 
      <ul>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li>
     <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li>
     <li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li> 
     <li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li> 
     <li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li> 
     <li><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you. :) @MercedesPennell